# Handlebar Each and JSON API call how do I get it to transfer the data from array response and put it on a handlebars modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, handlebars.js

```
$("#searchMovieBtn").click(() => {
const movieSource = $("#movie-template").html();
const movieList = Handlebars.compile(movieSource);
const movieSearch = $("#addMovie").val();
console.log(movieSearch);
queryURL = `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=${apiKey}&language=en-US&query=${movieSearch}&page=1&include_adult=false`;
$.ajax({
  url: queryURL,
  method: "GET"
}).then(response => {
  console.log(response);
  const results = response.results;
  const data = { movies: [] };
  for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    const currentTitle = {
      title: results[i].title,
      release_date: results[i].release_date
    };
    data.movies.push(currentTitle);
  }
  console.log(data);
  $("#placeholder").html(
    movieList({
      data: data
    })
  );
});
});
});
```

this is my function to call it

```
                <div id="placeholder"></div>
            <script type="text/x-handlebars-template" id="movie-template">
            <ul class="list-group">
                {{#each movies}}
                {{#each this}}
              <li class="list-group-item text-dark" id="MovieTitle">{{title}}
                <span>
                  (<span id="MovieYear">{{release_date}}</span>)
                  <span>
                    <button class="btn btn-warning text-light btn-sm" id="addMovieBtn">Add to watchlist</button>
                  </span>
                </span>
              </li>
              {{/each}}
              {{/each}}
            </ul>
            </script>
```

And what it is going into!
I have been up all night and just cannot figure out what is going on with it! I swear I have looked up and down and still cannot find the right method to use it is driving me mad! Anyways thanks for the help ahead of time I am sure it was something very very simple that I looked over a lot.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few errors in your solution.

First, you must understand the context object that you are passing to your template. It's shape looks like this:

```
{
  data: {
    movies: [
      {
        title: "Movie Title",
        release_date: "Year"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Notice that the first key in the object is `data`. However, in your template, you have no reference to data, but try to access `movies` directly, effectively skipping a reference. Given this data, the first `#each` in your template would need to be updated to:
`{{#each data.movies}}`

Your second problem is your second `#each` in your template. This `#each` iterates over each property of each movie in the `movies` array. So when you reference a property like `{{title}}` within this block, the full path of your reference is something like `data.movies[i].title.title`. There is an extra '.title' there because you are *not* within the context of the movie, but of one of its properties (`title` in this case).

To fix this, simply remove the second `#each`.

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/crfzLak7/) for your reference.

As an additional note: I would avoid including static element IDs inside of a loop. It means you will have duplicate IDs in your output and that is not valid HTML.